# How can I retrieve images from Firebase storage

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am new at swift platform .I'm trying to install image to Firebase storage. Then retrieve from database to my own app.I found some codes on internet and associate with each other. 
Image is not print on screen. 
How can I print image.

Here is my code:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("images").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            let images = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
            self.places.removeAll()
            for (_, value) in images {
                        let userToShow = historicalPlace()
                        if let img = value["place1"] as? String{

                            userToShow.historyImage = img

                            self.places.append(userToShow)

                }
            }
            self.historyTableView.reloadData()
        })
       ref.removeAllObservers()

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = historyTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historyCell", for: indexPath) as! historyCell


        cell.historyImage.downloadImage(from: places[indexPath.row].historyImage!)


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return places.count
    }

}


extension UIImageView {

    func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {
        let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }

}
```

and this is my database:

[image: Database]

I turned my read and write true.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at `FirebaseUI`, which has an integration with `SDWebImage`, so you can do this:

```
// Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
let reference: FIRStorageReference = ...;

// UIImageView in your ViewController
var imageView: UIImageView = ...;

// Load the image using SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImageWithStorageReference(reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

Per https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseStorageUI